# Merge Query takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MERGE dimS AS T
USING ccservertbl AS S 
        ON (T.iAID = S.ServerID) OR (T.iAID = S.SID) 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
          THEN INSERT (
                iAID,
                ConfigItemName,
                PropertyName,
                NetWorkDomainName,
                DataCenterTLA,
                RetireValueIND,
                AssetOnlyInd,
                LastUpdatedDtim,
                ODataServerID) 
           VALUES (
                S.SID, 
                S.Name, 
                S.PropertyDimension, 
                S.NetworkDomain,
                S.datacenterCode, 
                S.RetiredvalueInd, 
                S.IsAssetonly, 
                S.Modified,
                S.ID)
        WHEN MATCHED 
         THEN UPDATE 
            SET T.ConfigItemName = S.Name,
                T.PropertyName = S.PropertyDimension, 
                T.NetWorkDomainName = S.NetworkDomain,
                T.DataCenterTLA = S.datacenterCode, 
                T.RetireValueIND = S.RetiredvalueInd, 
                T.AssetOnlyInd = S.IsAssetonly, 
                T.LastUpdatedDtim = S.Modified,
                T.ODataServerID = S.ID;
```

Comment: Oh god, can you please properly indent the query? It is incomprehensible.

Comment: Also, post the execution plan.

Comment: So what don't go for whole data at a one time user ajax loader user particular data at one time that's all

Comment: The above query takes more than 15 hours But if I remove OR (T.iAdminConfigItemID = S.ServerID1) then it takes just 30 sec please help me to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Try not to access the whole objects `dimS` and `ccservertbl`.

For example replace

```
MERGE dimS AS T
USING ccservertbl AS S
```

with

```
;WITH TargetTable AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dimS
    WHERE <some slicing clause>
), SourceTable AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ccservertbl
    WHERE <some slicing clause>
)
MERGE TargetTable AS T
USING SourceTable AS S
```

Comment: That's only going to be slower in total. Smaller batches have advantages as well, but they almost never perform better. One big query can be optimized better.